# CodeIgniter Inner Join Doesn't work with Jamie Rumbelow's Base Model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, my-model-jami

I'm usingJamie Rumbelow's CodeIgniter Base Model for CRUD actions  . I need to list some data which is related in split across three tables: lista_almas, usuario,and almas. In MySQL, the query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM lista_almas
INNER JOIN alma
ON lista_almas.id_almas = alma.id_alma
INNER JOIN usuario
ON lista_almas.id_usuario = usuario.id_lista_almas
WHERE usuario.id_usuario = id_usuarios
```

How can I do it following the My_Model code syntax?

```
|table lista_almas(main table)|=>id_lista_almas, id_usuario, id_almas. 
|table almas (soul table)     |=>id_almas, name, lastname, death_date. 
|table usuarios (user table)  |=>id_usuario, name, lastName.
```

The thing is that i have a listo of souls which is related to a user and a soul. So i need to list all the soule related to a user (the user creates the sould)

https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model
this's the github link to My_Model

Comment: Show/draw your tables structure. Especially relationships between those.

Comment: Copy that code and edit your own question.

Comment: @Tpojka i just edit the question.

Comment: That seems like many to many tables. Although, I would propose Avenirer's MY_Model that consists all Jamie's one functions but with more functionalities though and is maintained regulary. Check [docs here](https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model) how to relate models - in that case you would have two models `Usuarios_m.php` and `Almas_m.php`.

Comment: thank you. i will try it